# Error detected trying to receive input as an integer in C#

Tags: c#, input, console.readline

I am trying to make a simple program where the user tries to guess numbers between 1 and 25 until they guess the right one. I am trying to make the input received as an integer so that I can use greater than and less than signs. When I use the command I found on another answer in this forum, it says that there is an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
        int score = 0;
        int add = 1;

        while (add == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Guess A Number Between 1 and 25");
            string input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            score += add;

            if (input == 18)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Did It!");
                Console.WriteLine("Your Score was " + score);
                break;
            }
            else if (input > 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try Again. Score: " + score);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `string input`? Aren't you converting the input to an `int`?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Will int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); work?

Answer (score 0):

Store their response from ReadLine() as a String, then use [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) to attempt to convert that String to an Integer.  The code below is written to show you all the possible states that could occur using `if else` blocks.  I've also used a `bool` to indicate when the game should end instead of using a `break` statement:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int number;
    string input;
    bool guessed = false;
    int score = 0;
    
    while (!guessed)
    {
        Console.Write("Guess A Number Between 1 and 25: ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();                
        if (int.TryParse(input, out number))
        {
            if(number>=1 && number<=25)
            {
                score++;
                if (number == 18)
                {
                    guessed = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("You Did It!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Your Score was " + score);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try Again. Score: " + score);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number must be between 1 and 25!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That's not a number!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```